# How many times does a nested for loop print out 'y'?

Tags: java

I have been looking at this example for a while now and i'm stuck, my question is how many times the statement:

```
System.out.println(y);
```

would be executed in the following code:

```
for(int x=0;x<N;x++){
  for(int y=x;y<N;y++){
    System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```

I was thinking it would surely be printed N+N-1+N-2(...) times right?
We are studying Big-O complexity but i'm struggling with this at the moment.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: What a question!  A+, for the effort

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion is to test it - it is code, it is meant to be run!

```
public static void runMe(int N) {
    int counter = 0;
    for(int x=0;x<N;x++){
      for(int y=x;y<N;y++){
        counter ++; // replacing the print
      }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

You will see the following values:

```
N counter
----------
0: 0
1: 1
2: 3
3: 6
4: 10
5: 15
6: 21
7: 28
8: 36
9: 45
10: 55
```

You can see that this corresponds to (N+1)*N / 2 = sum of i from i=1 to N. But there is a nicer, geometrical way of looking at this. Lets replace the numbers with asterisks:

```
public static void runMe(int N) {
    int counter = 0;
    for(int x=0;x<N;x++){
      for(int y=x;y<N;y++){
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The result, for N=8, is

```
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

A triangle with base 8 and height 8. Area of a triangle is base x height / 2. 8*9/2 = 4*9 = 36 (accept the +1 on height-or-width to fix rounding: it is not a perfectly smooth triangle after all). Geometry for the win!

If you remember the geometrical explanation for the area of the triangle, it holds here too (and it explains the +1): Lets cut-and-fold our triangle:

```
********/*
*******/**
******/***
*****/****
```

There you are: with even N, you cut the lower triangle, rotate it, and it will fit nicely with the upper triangle. N+1 on each of the N/2 rows = (N+1)*N/ 2

With odd N, you can leave the first row intact: here is the output for N=7

```
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

After folding: (N+1)/2 * N = (N*1) * N/2 = 28

```
*******/
******/*
*****/**
****/***
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's `N + (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ...`

Written the other way around, it's obviously the sum of the numbers from `1 .. N` which  has the well known solution of `0.5 * N * (N + 1)` which can also be written as `0.5 * (N^2 + N)`.

Since the `N^2` term dominates then in Big-O notation this is considered `O(N^2)` and the 0.5 constant factor is ignored.

Comment: The equation is 0.5*(N^2+N). Down vote since this answer is wrong. Also, he isn't asking about computational time he is asking about the exact number of times it will be printed.

Comment: I already fixed that (in fact I think the downvote happened before I even made that error when expanding `0.5 * N * (N+1)` ) and he does explicitly ask about Big-O complexity!

Comment: I missed the Big-O complexity. That part was correct.

Comment: @lacraig2 also, minor errors like that should normally be commented on so they get fixed, not down-voted

Answer (score 0):

The answer will print out the answer 1/2N(N+1) times on exactly 1/2N(N+1) lines.

For example for 1 it will print 1 time. For two it will print 3 times, for 3 it will print 6 times.

The pattern is: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28 and that pattern will always match

```
 F(x) = 1/2 x N x (N+1)
```

Hope this helps